# Login-AzureRmAccount Error after running the command

Tags: powershell, azure, authentication, servicebus

Getting the below error even though I've Run the `Login-AzureRmAccount` command and I've also selected my subscription using the `Select-AzureRmSubscription` command. I'm not sure what could be causing this. any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace : Run Login-AzureRmAccount to login.
    At line:1 char:2
    +  New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace -ResourceGroup AXFDEVRG -NamespaceNam ...
    +  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-AzureRmServiceBusNamespace], PSInvalidOperationException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperation,Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ServiceBus.Commands.Namespace.NewAzureRmServiceBusNamespace
```

Comment: I recently ran the Import-Module AzureRm.ServiceBus

Answer (score 1):

According to your error log, you could check as the following ways.

1.Try to create new Serviceus on Azure Portal. Please ensure your subscription has the permission to create SeviceBus.

2.Do you have multiple subscriptions? If yes, please ensure your subscription is correct.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount 
#View all subscriptions for your account
Get-AzureRmSubscription

#Select a default subscription for your current session

Get-AzureRmSubscription –SubscriptionName "your subscription" | Select-AzureRmSubscription
```

3.If they don't work, please check your Azure PowerShell version.

```
Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh
```

For now, the latest version is 3.7.0. If your are old version, you could try to install the latest version from the [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/releases/tag/v3.7.0-March2017).

Comment: I notice your another question, it seems your Azure PowerShell version is not latest. Please try to update your Azure PowerShell version firstly and try again.